# How to use Windows Edge Browser instead of IE in a eclipse swt application?

Tags: ecmascript-6, swt, microsoft-edge, rcp

I try to use EcmaScript 6 in my RCP Application including a webview. As I know IE just supports EcmaScript 5. So is it possible to use Edge instead of the default browser IE in swt?

Comment: There is an open enhancement request for this [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=538991) so I assume it is not yet possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=12001` in the `eclipse.ini`, then the used browser will be Microsoft Edge.